# Assertion error ignores click on any option

Tags: vb.net, assertion

When a Debug.Assert is hit in the code, a modal assertion error window pops up and offers the options "Cancel", "Repeat" and "Ignore".

When I click "Ignore", the IDE usually jumps to the code. 
However, after playing around with the Debug options, it doesn't do that anymore.

It doesn't react on "Cancel" or "Repeat" either.

How can I get it back to normal?